# Responsive design change menu jquery (or css) effect on resize

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to have an horizontal dropdown menu on the top right side of the desktop- and tablet-size and a harmonica effect on the phone-size for the same menu, but this time a vertical menu. Is this possible and how? Any tutorials or examples or other explanations are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes i have tried it, but not succeeded yet. I now have two menu's instead of one; set to 'display: none' for the dropdown' one on desktop size and one (accordion) for mobile size. And the accordion menu is not working so well (too narrow) on the mobile size. I would prefer to use just one menu, so if you have another solution please let me know. [link](http://www.dixdesign.net/test/menu/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

In simple steps, what you should do:

1. Make the list in HTML.
2. Style it for the desktop ([here's a tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) for "Suckerfish" style dropdowns)
3. Style it for mobile viewers using a [@media query](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) (I usually usa < 600px screen width for mobile). You probably want to hide the menu, along with some other changes.
4. Add an [accordion effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default) when the menu link is clicked.

If this doesn't work, next time give some specifics of what you tried, what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Here is what im working on: [link](http://www.dixdesign.net/test/menu/index.html)